# Calling Gradle commands and tasks with parameters from Gradle Task

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I have a current setup in my build.gradle that I'm trying to understand.  I need a number of tasks to go off in a very specific order and execute all with one task call.  The setup I want looks like this:

1.) Run liquibase changeset into predefined database
2.) Run a number of tests against database
3.) Rollback all changes made with the previous changeset

I want the database in a 'clean' state every time I test it.  It should have only the changes I expect and nothing else.  The liquibase is set up with the Gradle plugin for it and the changeset is applied/updated.  However, I don't want to call the command manually.  This will be something that needs to run in continuous integration, so I need to script it so I simply have our CI call one task and it then runs each task, in order, until the end.  I'm unsure of how to call the Gradle command-line task from inside of itself (ie inside the build.gradle file) and then also pass parameters to it (since I'll need to call some type of rollback command task to get the database to be what it was before calling the update).

Right now, all I'm doing is calling the command line tasks like this:

```
$ gradle update
$ gradle test
$ gradle rollbackToDate -PliquibaseCommandValue=2016-05-25
```

Again, I can't call them by the command line alone.  I need a custom task inside Gradle so that I could just call something like:

```
$ gradle runDatabaseTests
```

...And I would have it do everything I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no gradle way to invoke/call a task from another task directly. What you can do instead is to use `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy` to setup task dependencies which will force the prereq tasks to run first.

If you declare a task:

```
task runDatabaseTests(dependsOn: [update, test, rollbackToDate]) << {
    println "I depend on update, test and rollbackToDate"
}
```

when you call

```
gradle runDatabaseTests -PliquibaseCommandValue=2016-05-25
```

it will force update, test and rollbackToDate first. You can control the order in which they're run, if you care about that, by using `mustRunAfter` and/or `shouldRunAfter`

Comment: So, what I'm getting is that there's no way to run a task (which requires a parameter through commandline) from another task?  That makes automating a number of the commands I'm using almost impossible.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. Gradle tasks aren't like regular functions - So they require one to think a bit differently. There are ways to implement pretty much anything you want to do though. You can set the value of an ext variable and a subsequent task can use the ext variable for instance. (You can also create normal functions in a gradle script)